# How to speed up ExternalOptimizerInterface in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

I just did a benchmark and [ExternalOptimizerInterface](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/opt/ExternalOptimizerInterface) from the Tensorflow optimization package is almost twice as slow as a normal optimizer.

It makes me wonder what the point of it is. `ExternalOptimizerInterface` clearly unfeasible for modern deep learning. Is there anyway to speed up `ExternalOptimizerInterface`?

Here's a snippet of my ExternalOptimizer:

```
  def _minimize(self, initial_val, loss_grad_func, equality_funcs,
                equality_grad_funcs, inequality_funcs, inequality_grad_funcs,
                step_callback, optimizer_kwargs, packed_bounds=None):
    self.t += 1

    current_val = initial_val
    _, grad = loss_grad_func(current_val)

    delta = - grad * self.learning_rate
    new_val = current_val + delta

    return new_val
```

Comment: Can you add some code to show what your optimizer is doing ?

Comment: It's the standard gradient descent implemented with the ExternalOptimizerInterface. I benchmarked it against the `GradientDescentOptimizer`.

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned if you are running it on a GPU or CPU. Nevertheless, the performance difference comes from the fact that `GradientDescentOptimizer` uses a single optimized kernel. Your implementation using `ExternalOptimizerInterface` is implemented using primitive operations and Tensorflow cannot optimize across kernels.

The underlying kernel `ApplyGradientDescentOp` is defined here
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4aa639c0cbb47f4707f735e0cc80f4c39506d928/tensorflow/core/kernels/training_ops.cc#L423 )

you can run both the implementations and compare them using a profiler such as [tf-prof](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/profiler/README.md) for more details